# Put a scrollbar to a div and put the fetched data inside it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Hello i want to put a scroll bar to my div and put all the fetch data inside it. Can someone help me and give me ideas how to do it? im just starting to learn php and html.

here is the example of what i want to do. exactly the same.
[image]

and here is my work. i want to put a scrollbar to the 3 divs, the events, the news, and the announcements.
[image]

here is the code of news, events, and the annoucements.

```
   <div class="content">
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
     <div class="fix leftbar floatleft">
        <div class="fix left_sidebar">
           <div class="news">
              <h2><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i> Latest News</h2>
              <hr class="carved">


                     <?php
                     include_once('connection.php');
                     $sql ="SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY news_id ASC limit 4";
                     $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

                     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                     $title = $row['news_title'];
                     $date = $row['news_date'];
                     $content = $row['news_content'];
                     $newsimage = $row['news_image'];
                     ?>
                     <div class="fix single_news">
                       <div class="single_image">
                           <img src="<?php echo $newsimage; ?>" alt="court">
                       </div>
                       <a href="#"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
                       <p><?php echo $date; ?></p>
                     <p><?php echo $content; ?></p>
                     </div>
                      <hr>
                    <?php
                     }
                     ?>   


                <a href="#" class="view_news">View More News</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
   <div class="fix sidebar floatright">
        <div class="fix single_sidebar">
            <div class="events">
                <h2><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Upcoming events</h2>
                           <hr class="carved">
                            <div class="fix single_events">
                                <div class="date">
                                     <span class="month">August</span>
                                      <h1 class="day">28</h1>
                                 </div>
                                <h2>Independence Day</h2>
                                <p>7:00 AM - 8:00 PM</p>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="fix single_events">
                                <div class="date">
                                 <span class="month">August</span>
                                 <h1 class="day">28</h1>
                                 </div>
                                <h2>New Year</h2>
                                <p>7:00 AM - 8:00 PM</p>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="fix single_events">
                                 <div class="date">
                                 <span class="month">August</span>
                                 <h1 class="day">28</h1>
                                 </div>
                                <h2>Thesis Defense</h2>
                                <p>7:00 AM - 8:00 PM</p>
                            </div>
                                      <hr>
                            <a href="#" class="view_calendar">View Academic Calendar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="fix bottombar floatright">
        <div class="fix bottom_bar">
            <div class="announcements">
                        <h2><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i> Announcements</h2>
                           <hr class="carved">
                            <div class="fix single_announce">
                                <a href="#">Sample Announcements</a>
                            </div> 

                            <div class="fix single_announce">
                                <a href="#">Sample Announcements</a>
                            </div> 

                            <div class="fix single_announce">
                                <a href="#">Sample Announcements</a>
                            </div> 

                            <div class="fix single_announce">
                                <a href="#">Sample Announcements</a>
                            </div> 

                            <div class="fix single_announce">
                                <a href="#">Sample Announcements</a>
                            </div> 

                            <div class="fix single_announce">
                                <a href="#">Sample Announcements</a>
                            </div> 

                            <div class="fix single_announce">
                                <a href="#">Sample Announcements</a>
                            </div> 

                                      <hr>
                            <a href ="#" class="view_announcements">View more announcements</a>

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
   </div>


    </div>

  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: im sorry, ill edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the div to scroll, set the height and overflow to scroll

```
.scrollDiv{
    display:block;
    max-height:150px; /*Put your maximum height here*/
    overflow-y:scroll; /*Tell it to scroll if the content is larger than max-height*/
}
```

Comment: Hi sir. the height of the div is auto, should i still add the max-height?

Comment: I would think you would want the div to stop expanding at some point so I would say yes

Comment: At some point can the "Latest news" just stay at the top of that div and just news are scrolling? like the "affix" of the bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, just only add the .scrollDiv class to each of the elements that should have a scroll and leave the rest alone

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your css file:

> scrollable {
>       overflow-y: scroll; }

In your html, in each div you want to make scrollable add the class *scrollable*.

The *overflow-y* code specifies what you would like to do when the y axis (the height) of the div or any element exceeds its current height. The *scroll* specifies that under this condition it needs to be scrollable.